# Does WCF support Chunked Transfer Encoding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http

Does WCF support [Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)? I've been looking on the Web but I couldn't find much on the subject. My WCF REST APIs are all using [WebOperationContext.CreateStreamResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782275.aspx) to return a response to the client. Using that APIs on the WebOperationContext, I was hoping that the Transfer-Encoding: chunked would be turned on.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does support it, but it needs to be set at the transport binding. If you're using the `WebHttpBinding`, you can set the `TransferMode` property to `TransferMode.Streamed` If you're using a custom binding, you can set that property on the `HttpTransportBindingElement`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I receive a message with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` then the XmlObjectSerializer shows up with this exception message: There was an error checking start element of object of type XYZ. Encountered unexpected character '­'.